# Ativar Javascript dentro de uma Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Preciso fazer um slideToggle na janela de uma Fancybox. O método normal de pegar o `(elemento).click(functiom(){...})` eu sei que não funciona. Só sei que devemos usar o `.on()` do jQuery mas não sei como faz isso e quem souber gostaria de uma breve explicação ou link para um conteúdo bom com relação a isso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O atribuição de eventos com `on` do jQuery é indicada para adicionar eventos a elementos dinamicamente criados.

O melhor lugar para entender sobre o `on` é na [própria documentação do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Aqui vão exemplos de como usar:

Você pode usar o on como um sinônimo do `click`, da seguinte maneira:

```
$('#elemento').on('click', function() { 
});
```

Porém isso não funciona para elementos dinamicamente criados (como deve ser o caso do Fancybox). Para funcionar com tais elementos, deve-se configurar o evento a partir de um elemento pai do elemento que deseja adicionar o evento, por exemplo:

```
$('#elemento-pai').on('click', '#elemento', function() { 
});
```

Você deve então estudar o plugin que está usando e ver como é o Html que ele gera. Procure o elemento pai ao qual deseja atribuir o evento e faça como no segundo exemplo. Lembrando que pode usar qualquer seletor para adicionar o evento, no exemplo eu usei o seletor de id ("#") só para ilustrar.

Comment: Era isso que eu estava tentando fazer mas não deu certo. Tentei pegar a classe da fancybox como pai, o próprio pai do elemento e nada.

Comment: Você quer adicionar um efeito de slide ao fechar o modal do fancybox, é isso?